# How to show for a f.g. graded ring $R$, $R^{(m)}$ is generated by degree $1$ for some $m$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $$R=\oplus_{i\geq 0} R_i$$ be a graded ring, which is finitely generated as a $R_0$ algebra. Let $R^{(m)}$ be $\oplus_{i\geq 0} R_{mi}$. Then how to show that for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $R^{(m)}$ is generated by the elements in $R_m$ over $R_0$ (i.e. the degree $1$ elements of $R^{(m)}$).

I think this is the well-known fact, hence the paper I am reading gives a very sketchy proof which is as follows:

> > Proof. Let $Y = {\rm Proj}(R)$, then for some $m>0$, $H^0(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y(km)) = R_{km}$ for all $k>0$. The result follows.

Can anyone elaborate on how the "result follows" or give another proof?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: I believe Mumford also outlines this in the _Red Book_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then this is Proposition 3 from Bourbaki, Commutative Algebra, page 159, and it shows exactly what you have in your proof: the property holds for all multiples of some m>0. (As a side note, the proof given by Bourbaki is quite elementary.)